# Is it possible to control 8 servos with single arduino uno through wifi?

Tags: wifi, arduino-uno

I am new to everything arduino related and I have pretty limited experience in circuitry. I picked up an arduino uno a little while ago without a project in mind. I have recently decided on one but require a little guidance.

I am attempting to make a clock of sorts using 8 servos that are controlled based on info collected from a php script pulling info from facebook. Each servo turns a gear that controls a hand on the clock(8 hands total). I've looked into a few different wifi shields(esp8266, cc3000, arduino shield) but I'm confused on their pin placement. It seems that they take up too much space to be able to use a wifi shield in addition to 8 servos on a single arduino uno? So is there any sort of way to fit all 8 servos and a wifi shield on a single arduino uno? Also, I realize that the arduino is not going to be able to power the servos alone, therefore needing a separate power supply. Would some kind of wall wart be suitable for this purpose? The servos I am looking at operate at 4.8-6 volts(HiTec HS-422). I'm not concerned about the programming side of things as I am a developer, but I have been having a tough time with the hardware. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible to control 12 servos with arduino uno. But if you use a wi-fi module, you need to give it 2 pins. So you can connect 10 servos.

See this link:

http://2xod.com/articles/Arduino_Wifi_With_Hi_Flying_HF-LPT100_or_USR-WIFI232/